# Unable to shutdown/sleep laptop (ASUS N55SL)

Tags: laptop, sleep, shutdown

I have a problem with sleep and shutdown on my ASUS N55SL-S2115V laptop. I have a clean Windows 7 64bit installation on it. It is not that clean, because it is full of ASUS "super" apps. The problem is that when I press the sleep button, laptop stays "partially" on. Display is off, but I can hear at least one fan running. The same thing happens when I want to shutdown the laptop. There is no problem with restart.

I have tried to fix it by removing almost all ASUS applications (like ASUS Instant On) with no luck.

Comment: Do you get any details in the event log?

Comment: Are you sure that your options, say that when the lid is closed, that the computer goes to sleep?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the sleep uses the Suspend-toRAM where your data is stored in memory (for faster awake). The same is true with hibernate, using SuspendToDisk.

Try to change this in the power options of your laptop.

With your model, some of the power management is actually controlled via the BIOS.

[See page 36 on the manual](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Asus/N55SL/Manual/261970)

Comment: That did not help. Still having same problem. But thx for advice!

Comment: Which part - updating it in the BIOS or via the Power Options within Windows?

Comment: Both. I'll try Ubuntu from Live CD